MacBook: how to enable built-in camera in clamshell mode?
Yes I know this sounds weird. But here's my use case: I am converting an iMac into an external display and want to reuse the camera. This particular one is just a USB camera and I have already figured out the pinout. It works fine on PCs, as well as MacBooks as long as the lid is open. However, if the lid is closed, macOS disables it because it thinks it's a built-in camera. So I see a couple of options here:

Change the USB descriptor to fool macOS into thinking it's not an apple camera.
Make macOS not to disable it in clamshell mode.

I very much doubt the first option is viable, unless someone has a way to read and write the firmware. Does anyone have any idea about option 2 though?
Thanks.
